# Representativeness of sample, distribution of age from sample compared to national sample

Tags: distributions, sample, representative

Please forgive my entry-level question. I have been slamming my head on the table for well over 3 hours now as I cannot seem to figure this one out.

I have a sample of n=450, population is about 17m. For my thesis I am writing something about how my sample is representative for the entire population. For this, I seek to say something about the age distribution. But how can I compare these two?

I know the exact counts of every age in my sample, as well as in my population. So the excel I have made has in the first column the ages (1y/o to 99 y/o), the second column the counts from my sample, the third column are the counts from the nation.

I have tried ANOVA's, crosstabls and a whole range of other analysis. Independent-sample T-test seem the most logical to me but i am not sure how to configure the two categories. Averages report not the average age, but rather the average count, so I think my reasoning is off somewhere.

I am rather stuck as you might have noticed and hope someone here can offer some help!

Thank you, and with kind regards from holland!

Comment: Excel makes it easy to construct a scatterplot of the two columns.  (It would be best first to switch columns B and C.)  One hopes the points line up along a diagonal line of the form $y=px.$  If they don't, you have a clear indication that (a) the sample does differ from the population; (b) you can *see* the age groups where that difference occurs; and (c) you can *see* any patterns of discrepancy that might exist. Although you may perform a 1D chi-squared test (based on the age proportions in the population), it won't reveal anywhere near as much as that simple plot.

Comment: Ah, perfect! Thank you so much!